# converting downloaded file to pdf throws error in cypress

Tags: typescript, pdf, download, cypress

in plugins file cypress

```
 on('task', {
        readFile(filename) {
          if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
            return pdf.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'));
          }
          return null;
        },
      });
```

and in my code i am using readfile as:

```
 isUserRemovedFromExport(status: string, trainee: string, document: string) {
        const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder');
        usersUtil.getCurrentCompany().then((company) => {
          const filename = `${dates.getShortFormattedToday()}-${company.name}-document-${document}-training-data.pdf`;
          const downloadFileName = path.join(downloadsFolder, filename);
          cy.readFile(downloadFileName).should('have.text', trainee);
        });
      }
    }
```

when i do so i get following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvaes.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftsjT.png)

I have also tried :

```
 on('task', {
    getPdfContent(obj) {
      const pdfPathname = path.join(Cypress.config('downloadsFolder'), obj);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const data = pdf.parse(fs.readFileSync(pdfPathname));
          resolve(data);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    },
  });
```

but the above block throws error at cy.task as cypress not defined

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually calling the task.

`cy.readFile()` is a built-in command, not your custom task.

Try this

```js
cy.task('readFile', downloadFileName)
  .should('have.text', trainee);
```

---

The 2nd version looks ok too, but running in Node it has no access to `Cypress` as you mentioned.

You can pass two params in `obj`

**test**

```js
const filename = `${dates.getShortFormattedToday()}-${company.name}-document-${document}-training-data.pdf`;

// Make a single parameter for task
const params = {
  filename, 
  downloadsFolder: Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')
}

cy.task('getPdfContent', params).should('have.text', trainee)
```

**task**

```js
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');

on('task', {
    getPdfContent(obj) {

      const { 
        filename,             // should be small 'n'
        downloadsFolder 
      } = obj;

      const pdfPathname = path.join(downloadsFolder, filename);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {

          // from https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse
          pdf(fs.readFileSync(pdfPathname)).then(function(data) {
            resolve(data);
          })

        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    },
  });
```

**Notes**

- can't use `path.join()` in the test because it's Node command.
- task can only receive one parameter, so combined the `downloadsFolder` and `fileName` in  single object.

Comment: I got below error while trying the mentioned solution as `cy.task('getPdfContent') failed with the following error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined`

Comment: See above, add the 2nd parameter as shown - an object with two properties.

Comment: Have tried exactly as you mentioned i receive the error as mentioned in my above comment

Comment: for typescript do i need any extra configurations like i have tsconfig.json file do i need webpack.config.js as well ?

Comment: Ok, got it - change `fileName` to `filename` in the task.

Comment: `Thanks for helping` , modified as suggested, now i get error as `pdf.parse is not a function`, i have "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1", in my package.json and also `const pdf = require('pdf-parse');` in my plugins file

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that earlier - take a look at the npm pdf-parse page, I think the syntax is different.